# How to display quick links dynamically in SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages, quick-links

I am displaying few links through quick link webpart in SP modern page. Day by day new links get added.

Now I want this section to auto display the newly added quick links also. Is it possible here?

or any work around. please suggest.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using similar quick links web parts on multiple pages? If not, when you add new link in the web part, it should show automatically.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint out of the box Quick Links web part or any custom web part? Referring to `Day by day new links get added` - how you are adding new links every day, manually or using any automation? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using similar quick links web parts on multiple SharePoint site pages and you want to add new links in one place which should be shown in all quick links web parts, try below solutions.

**Using JSON formatting**:

You can use the SharePoint list to store information related to links (link title, link/URL, etc.) and use JSON formatting to customize the display of links.

Then add "List" web part on home page (where you want to show the links) and show the JSON formatted customized list on the page.

This gives you better flexibility over the design and you can manage (add/remove/hide based on flag column or by creating different filtered views) the quick links from SharePoint list without editing the site pages.

Check below samples which should help you with this:

1. [Honeycomb Links](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/honeycomb-link)

   [image]
2. [Icon Link Tiles](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/icon-link-tiles)

   [image]

**Using SharePoint framework (SPFx)**:

You can also use custom web parts developed using SPFx for showing the quick links dynamically on site pages.

Here are few samples to show the capabilities of SPFx development for quick links:

1. [Custom Links](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-custom-links)
2. [Links Web Part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-links)